# Is there a way to check the color on a text in RCPTT?

Tags: eclipse-rcptt

Not the foreground/background color, but the color of the text itself.

I need to verify the result text by color (red/green).

Answer (score 0):

The foreground color is the color of the text in case of a Text field.

What kind of Widget are trying to verify?